# Events in Actionscript: How to get the instance name value by clicking the object on stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

```
// I created four instance of movieclip on stage and named them t1_mc,t2_mc,t3_mc,t4_mc 

// Then I made and array and loaded them inside the array

var arr1:Array = new Array( t1_mc, t2_mc, t3_mc, t4_mc );


var names:String;


//function made to add event listener to each object

function addListner():void

{

       for ( var i:uint = 0; i < arr1.length; i++ )

                   {

                  // Here We are creating four eventlisteners with a function  dispNm

                     names = arr1[i].name;
                       names + arr1[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dispNm);

                   }

}

// this will run the function

addListner();

//next I created the dispNm method in this I am trying to get the value "t1" in output by clicking the object named "t1_mc" but I get error!!!!! 

"1119: Access of possibly undefined property target through a reference with static type Class."

function dispNm(e:MouseEvent):void

{

    if( Event.target.name == 't1_mc')

    {

        trace('t1');

    }

}
```

i don't know where Im wrong

Please help......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dispNm(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ur a superhero i got what i was lookin for bt can u explain a little bit that what actually happend....!!!...

Comment: "Event" is a type (a class name), the "e" function parameter is the reference to the specific instance of MouseEvent which is being handled by your listener and has the "target" value you need. The only time you ever use the format ClassName.property is when you're accessing class static members, which "target" is not.